# How to avoid opening a QuickInput when choosing files to compare in a vscode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In my case I want to compare two files.
But I don't want the user to select the File in the QuickInput form, i want to choose this directly for him.

`vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.files.action.compareFileWith", filePath)`

This results in

[image: VSCode Quickpick]

Meaning that `filePath` is ignored and a QuickInput is displayed instead.
Is there a way to directly select a file programmatically instead of showing the QuickInput first?

Comment: I updated my answer to show a way to do what you want using the other `compare` commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the `compareFileWith` command probably requires a QuickInput panel to use, you can use the other `compare` commands to do what you want:

```js
// using the current file for the 'compareWith' file
const currentFileUri = vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.uri;

// create a Uri from some filePath
const compareWithSelectedUri = vscode.Uri.file('C:\\Users\\Mark\\OneDrive\\Test Bed\\BAR.txt');

await vscode.commands.executeCommand('selectForCompare', currentFileUri)
await vscode.commands.executeCommand('compareFiles', compareWithSelectedUri);
```

This works in my testing.

---

Looking at `compareFileWith` in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/9b9361cfd1b0678f0bb0b32bf9925b6520bb9926/src/vs/workbench/contrib/files/browser/fileActions.ts I don't think there is any way to avoid the QuickInput opening.

Alternatively, what you are asking for would be "easy" if an `open` method were supported on [TabGroups api](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TabGroups) like the `close` methods.  You would create a tab of kind `TabInputTextDiff` with an original uri and a modifieed uri.

When the `TabGroups` api was being developed there was an `open` tab method but it was removed prior to release and hasn't seen any love since.  See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/aa69f3d7623c464aba726d12ea0d83428f43e8b9#commitcomment-71831337.

I'll open an issue to see if it will help (and post the link here later).

Comment: thank you very much, this works fine!
Interesting to see that `selectForCompare` and `compareFiles` are not prefixed with `workbench.action...` or similar. 
The command for "compareWith" was `workbench.files.action.compareFileWith` for example. 
This seems arbitrary for me on first glance...

Comment: Yes, there are a small number of such commands, maybe old ones that were implemented before a more systematic naming scheme was developed...